# Excel Formula to Sum with and without hidden rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Simply put, I'm looking to have a totals cell that can swap between including all prices, and including all visible prices (exclude hidden values).

I want to check if column C is Filtered, if it is use a function, if it isn't use a different function.

Here is a description of the layout:

[[Excel Table][1]http://imgur.com/S8ieGuv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a6WE.png)

I can use the AGGREGATE functions to do the swap, my problem is with the IF statement for IF the column is filtered or not.

This is what I currently have:

=IF(ColumnIsFiltered, AGGREGATE(9,7,A2:A7),AGGREGATE(9,6,A2:A7))

The aggregate functions work as intended, but I cannot find anything to substitute for the "ColumnIsFiltered" part.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With data in column **A**, here is one way to tell if all the data is visible or some has been filtered out:

```
=IF(COUNTA(A:A)=SUBTOTAL(3,A:A),"all visible","not all visible")
```

[image]

Naturally, you would replace the text with AGGREGATE functions .

Comment: Yes! This works. I didn't think to count if what is there matches how many there is with it unfiltered.

Comment: @Alex  The real issue is not *"is there filtering?"*, the real is is *"is anything hidden?"*